# Pandas - how to sort two DataFrames according to the order given by one of them?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

If I have one Pandas `DataFrame` that I wish to sort by one of its columns, can I then have a separate `DataFrame` sorted together with it, i.e. so that the sort performs the same permutations on the other `DataFrame` as it does on the one being sorted?

Please note that I cannot rely on the row indices of the two `DataFrame`s to be in the same order initially.

**Additional info**
The solution by @ami-tavory does not seem to work for me with `.ix` indexing. It does, however, work if I change that to `.iloc`. I cannot reproduce this on @ami-tavory's example code, but the dataframes I am working with have this layout:

```
>>> fails_sorted_old.dtypes
image                        object
sampling_pattern             object
delta                       float64
reconstruction_algorithm     object
psnr                        float64
ssim                        float64
time                        float64
dtype: object

>>> fails_sorted_old.shape
(126, 7)
```

When I do:

```
idx_by_old_psnr = fails_sorted_old.psnr.argsort()
```

then:

```
fails_sorted_old.ix[idx_by_old_psnr]
```

gives me a `DataFrame` full of `NaN`s while this works fine:

```
fails_sorted_old.iloc[idx_by_old_psnr]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you start with two dataframes:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 4, 3], 
    'b': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'f': range(4), 
})
```

So that:

```
>> df0
    a   b
 0  1   a
 1  2   b
 2  4   c
 3  3   d

>> df1
    f
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

Now, using [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), you can find the indices of `df0` sorted by `a`:

```
import numpy as np

sorted_inds = np.argsort(df0.a)
```

And, with those, (having done a single sort) you can sort the dataframes:

```
df0 = df0.ix[sorted_inds]
df1 = df1.ix[sorted_inds]
```

So you have:

```
>> df0
    a   b
0   1   a
1   2   b
3   3   d
2   4   c

>> df1
    f
0   0
1   1
3   3
2   2
```

Comment: Strangely, when I index my dataframes using `.ix` as you do above the result is a dataframe full of `NaN`s. If I replace `.ix` by `.iloc` instead, it seems to work.

Comment: Post a small example of the problem?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it with your example, but the somewhat larger dataframes I am trying to juggle fail.

Comment: I have added a bit of example to my question. I cannot easily reproduce the problem with a more paste-able example `DataFrame`...

Comment: By the way, it seems you could also use `df0.a.argsort()` instead of `np.argsort(df0.a)` if you prefer to stay in the Pandas namespace.

Comment: :-) Was not aware that ``argsort`` made it into pandas. Thanks.